# How to do group by in sql and put all values in group to list?

Tags: sql

I want to do group by in sql and put all values in group to list?

for example if my table is:

```
col1       col2    col3
a         john      c
a         john      l
a         mike      m
b         Karl      i
b         Karl      j
```

i want to grub by col1 and col2 and put values from col3 from each group in list. desired output:

```
col1       col2    col3
a         john      [c, l]
a         mike      [m]
b         Karl      [i, j]
```

how could i do that?

Comment: Please dont spam tags. Which database are you actually using, tag just that one

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect ___some effort from you___ to solve your own problem before asking a question. So show us your best effort. 
___SO is not a free coding service___, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using MySQL, you could try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(col3 SEPARATOR ", "), "]") AS col3
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

If your intention is for col3 to be a JSON array, then it becomes even simpler:

```
SELECT col1, col2, JSON_ARRAYAGG(col3) AS col3
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```